# Getting column names based on df.query condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'Car':[1,2,3,4],'Renault':[1,0,0,0],'Volkswagen':[0,1,0,0],'Porsche':[0,0,1,0],'Mercedes':[1,1,0,0]})
```

That looks like:

```
    Car  Renault  Volkswagen  Porsche  Mercedes
0    1        1           0        0         1
1    2        0           1        0         1
2    3        0           0        1         0
3    4        0           0        0         0
```

At some point I build a dictionary with some query-like strings:

```
getCountry= {}
getCountry['isGerman']= ['(`Volkswagen`== 1)','((`Porsche`== 1) or (`Mercedes` == 1))']
```

When running:

```
for cond,all_qs in getCountry.items():
df_data[cond]=0
for qs in all_qs:
    df_data.loc[df_data.query(qs).index, cond] = 1
```

This trigger the correct results:

```
    Car  Renault  Volkswagen  Porsche  Mercedes  isGerman
0    1        1           0        0         1         1
1    2        0           1        0         1         1
2    3        0           0        1         0         1
3    4        0           0        0         0         0
```

What I need is an extra column letting me know why the isGerman column was 1, for example an extra column that would look like:

```
    Car  Renault  Volkswagen  Porsche  Mercedes  isGerman  isGermanDetails 
0    1        1           0        0         1         1       Mercedes
1    2        0           1        0         1         1       Volkswagen, Mercedes
2    3        0           0        1         0         1       Porsche
3    4        0           0        0         0         0
```

This new column should contain all the '1' column names from the different queries.

Thought of grouping all the columns for isGerman and ideally have a sql-like query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME WHERE Volkswagen = 1 or Porsche = 1 or Mercedes = 1.
```

I need to know which columns have made the isGerman go to 1, even if it is set to 1 multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Redefine your present approach

```
country = {'German': ['Volkswagen', 'Porsche', 'Mercedes']}

for k, v in country.items():
    df_data[f'Is{k}'] = df_data[v].any(1).astype(int)
    df_data[f'Is{k}Details'] = (df_data[v] @ (pd.Index(v) + ', ')).str[:-2]
```

---

```
print(df_data)

   Car  Renault  Volkswagen  Porsche  Mercedes  IsGerman       IsGermanDetails
0    1        1           0        0         1         1              Mercedes
1    2        0           1        0         1         1  Volkswagen, Mercedes
2    3        0           0        1         0         1               Porsche
3    4        0           0        0         0         0
```

Comment: Your approach is really good! But I see I failed in my example, what would happen if in the conditions there would be also an =0? The any(1) would not be anymore valid for you, right? Like (Renault=0 and Mercedes=1)

Comment: @AlejandroA I think then we have to modify the code to account for the condition when  there can be 0 .

Comment: @Subham Sharma Oh damn! Do you see it being very different/hard?

Comment: @AlejandroA I would not say hard surely its doable. Lemme think.

Comment: Will give you the valid answer, would appreciate if you can give some thought to that question, really thankful!

Comment: @AlejandroA Give me some time..I'll ping you back in an hour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234957/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-alejandro-a).

Comment: @AlejandroA Can you join the discussion room?